# How many deterministic finite-stata automata can I build with this info?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, automata

I am trying to solve the following question regarding FSA:

"Suppose that $ S $ and $I $ are finite sets such that $|S| = n $ and $|I | = k$.  How many different deterministic finite-state automata $M = (S, I, f, s0 , F )$ are there where the starting state $s0$"

I think the solution might be found using the product rule. The number of possible automata we can build is equal to the number of ways in which I can perform three different tasks: choosing the starting state $s0$, that is unique, chosing the set of final states $F$ and choosing the number of different functions from $S\times I$ to $S$ that we can find.

The number of all the possible $F$ is the cardinality of the power-set fo $S$: $2^{n}$

The number of all possible starting states is the cardinality of $S$: $n$

The number of possible functions from $S\times I$ to $S$ is $n$ multiplied with itself $ |S\times I|  $ $ = nk$ times, so $n^{nk}$ is the number of possible functions.

Therefore, we should have $n^{nk} $ $ \times $ $n$ $ \times $ $2^{n}$ deterministic finite state automata.

Is this the correct solution to the problem?

Comment: It is correct. Every automata is defined by it set of states, the alphabet, the initial state, the acceptins states and the transition function. When you are given the first two, the initial state has $n$ options, the accepting states have $2^{n}$ options, and the transition function as you mentioned oorrecly sends a pair of a state and letter to state therefor there are $(n)^{nk}$, multiplying all of this gives the number of different FSA with $n$ states and $k$ letters.